# How to get geometry type of a layer?

Tags: openlayers, geoserver

I am producing my layers like this:

```
// Vector source for geoserver services
const vectorSource = (layer) => {
  return new ol.source.Vector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    url: (extent) => {
      return (`http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Bugra/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=Bugra:${layer}&outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:3857&bbox=${extent.join(',')},EPSG:3857`);
    },
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
  })
};
```

and then using this one:

```
// Layer creating class
class LayerCreator {
  constructor(
    lyrName, lyrGeoServerName, lyrStrokeColor,
    lyrStrokeWidth, lyrFillColor, lyrOpacity,
    lyrPointRadius, lyrMinZoom, lyrMaxZoom,
    lyrLabelField, lyrFontFamily, lyrFontFillColor,
    lyrFontStrokeColor, lyrFontStrokeWidth, lyrFontBold,
    lyrFontSize, lyrFontPlacement, lyrFontOffsetY) {

    return new ol.layer.Vector({
      className: `${lyrName}-${lyrGeoServerName}`,
      source: vectorSource(lyrGeoServerName),
      style: function text(feature) {
        return new ol.style.Style({
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: lyrStrokeColor,
            width: lyrStrokeWidth,
          }),
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: lyrFillColor
          }),
          image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: lyrPointRadius,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
              color: lyrFillColor
            }),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
              color: lyrStrokeColor,
              width: lyrStrokeWidth,
            })
          }),
          text: new ol.style.Text({
            text: feature.get(lyrLabelField),
            font: `${lyrFontBold} ${lyrFontSize}px ${lyrFontFamily}`,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
              color: lyrFontFillColor,
            }),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
              color: lyrFontStrokeColor,
              width: lyrFontStrokeWidth,
            }),
            placement: lyrFontPlacement,
            offsetY: lyrFontOffsetY
          }),
        })
      },
      opacity: lyrOpacity,
      minZoom: lyrMinZoom,
      maxZoom: lyrMaxZoom,
    });
  }
}
```

The problem is, I got a Draw widget and as you know it needs a "type" value to know what of type of geometry it will create. I got a combobox with all 10 layers whic i created just like above. They are ol.layer.Vector type objects. So i have to dynamically change Draw widgets "type" value according to the geometry type of the layer that i choose from combobox. If it's type is "MultiPolygon" i have to send it to Draw widget as 'type: "MultiPolygon"' but i couldn't fetch the geometry type from ol.layer.Vector objects.

Can you help me pls?

[ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISjoX.png)

Comment: Layers do not have a geometry type s they can contain features with a mix of types.  But if you know each of your sources should be made up of only one type you could simply check the type of its first feature `layer.getSource().getFeatures()[0].getGeometry().getType()`

Comment: Dear Mike, I knew you were going to answer this question! I thought about this solution before but i was wondering if there is any other way. If you don't know any other solution then I think there is not any so i am going to use it. Thank you Mike! (again)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it properly you can make a `DescribeFeature` request which will give you the full schema of the featuretype including the geometry type.

For example:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver-2.17.2/ows?service=wfs&version=1.1.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&typeName=topp:states
```

returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.openplans.org/topp">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/geoserver-2.17.2/schemas/gml/3.1.1/base/gml.xsd"/>
  <xsd:complexType name="statesType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="the_geom" nillable="true" type="gml:MultiSurfacePropertyType"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="STATE_NAME" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="STATE_FIPS" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="SUB_REGION" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="STATE_ABBR" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="LAND_KM" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="WATER_KM" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="PERSONS" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="FAMILIES" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="HOUSHOLD" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="MALE" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="FEMALE" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="WORKERS" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="DRVALONE" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="CARPOOL" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="PUBTRANS" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="EMPLOYED" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="UNEMPLOY" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="SERVICE" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="MANUAL" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="P_MALE" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="P_FEMALE" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="SAMP_POP" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:element name="states" substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature" type="topp:statesType"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

So this layer contains `gml:MultiSurfacePropertyType` or MultiPolygons to you and me.

Comment: This one is also a nice solution! I have already found Geoserver REST API, there you can query nearly the same solution. (actually your solution uses the same API I suppose?)

Comment: Better still specify `outputFormat=application/json` so it can be easily read in JavaScript and will include `localType` in the format used by OpenLayers.

Answer (score 0):

Again Mike answered the question.

layer.getSource().getFeatures()[0].getGeometry().getType() gives you the geometry type of a layer (since layers can have mix of types)